# Keras LearningRateScheduler isn't executing due to an output type error

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I am working on a neural network that is having issues in that it will run as expected for maybe 20 epochs and then the accuracy suddenly plummets. I've read that it could be an issue with the learning rate and decreasing the learning rate value via a learning rate schedule might be the solution. I'm using the `Keras LearningRateScheduler` to try this. I am having an issue with the model accepting the new learning rates. It will run for the first ten epochs. When the rate is changed for the first time, it gives this error: `ValueError: The output of the "schedule" function should be float.` I have tried casting the return values using `float()` with no luck. I can't seem to find any explanation that makes sense. I'm hoping someone here can help me.

I am using Python on Google Colab GPU to do this. The code for the network is below. Please let me know if more info is needed.

```
X_train, X_validate, Y_train, Y_validate=train_test_split(X,Y,test_size=0.2)

from keras.backend import sigmoid

def swish(x):
  return (x*sigmoid(x))

from keras.utils.generic_utils import get_custom_objects
from keras.layers import Activation
get_custom_objects().update({'swish': Activation(swish)})

model=Sequential()

model.add(Dense(1024, activation='swish',input_shape=(6,)))
model.add(Dense(512, activation='swish'))
model.add(Dense(256, activation='swish'))
model.add(Dense(128, activation='swish'))
model.add(Dense(64, activation='swish'))
model.add(Dense(32, activation='swish'))
model.add(Dense(16, activation='swish'))
model.add(Dense(10, activation='softmax'))

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

from keras.callbacks import LearningRateScheduler

def scheduler(epochs, lr):
  if epochs < 10:
    return 0.001
  elif 10 < epochs < 20:
    return 0.0005
  elif 20 < epochs < 30:
    return 0.00025
  elif 30 < epochs < 50:
    return 0.000125
  elif 50 < epochs < 75:
    return 0.0000625
  elif 75 < epochs:
    return 0.0000313

callback=LearningRateScheduler(scheduler, verbose=1)

model.fit(X_train, Y_train, batch_size=75, epochs=50, callbacks=[callback], verbose=1) #Line referenced in error

model.summary()

score=model.evaluate(X_validate, Y_validate, verbose=1)
print("The loss and accuracy of the validation set are: "+str(score))

x=X_validate[52]
y=np.argmax(Y_validate[52])

y_pred=model.predict(np.array([x]))
y_pred=np.argmax(y_pred)

print("For the input data, the known mode is: "+str(y))
print("For the input data, the predicted mode is: "+str(y_pred))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. The return value can't simply be a value for the learning rate. Instead, it requires that a function be passed. For example: `return lr * math.exp(-0.1)`.

Also, the schedule has seemed to solve my previous issue of the accuracy dropping suddenly.

Answer (score 0):

```
   return 0.001
  elif 10 < epochs < 20:
    return 0.0005
  elif 20 < epochs < 30:
    return 0.00025
  elif 30 < epochs < 50:
    return 0.000125
  elif 50 < epochs < 75:
    return 0.0000625
  elif 75 < epochs:
    return 0.0000313
```

For each return , do the calculation as part of return statement only

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow , please highlight the codes that you put in your answer , I suggest you read this page https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).